# change default permission of files and folders which create by php

Tags: permissions, ubuntu-10.04

When I create a file by `exec()` or other php functions, permissions is `600` and for folders is 700.

How can I change it without `chmod()` or other like functions to `644` and folders to `755`.

Server detail:

- server os: ubuntu 10.04
- suphp installed
- PHP Version 5.3.2-1ubuntu4.14
- SERVER_SOFTWARE: apache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permissions files are created with are specified with [umask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) on Unix. There is a php function to alter this; see [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php) for the php function.

To change the permissions that Apache has, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428416/setting-the-umask-of-the-apache-user)

Comment: i need to change default parmissions in server configuration.

Comment: I'll edit my post to have the apache info in for you:

Comment: Good answer. I wouldn't chang ethe global umask of the Apache user though, just change with PHP before you need to create a file or directory with it.

Comment: I concur with @Yanick. Altering the actual init script has two problems. 1.) Altering the init.d scripts will be a nuisance to maintain as apt-get may update the init.d scripts if they alter in future (and systemd doesn't use init.d scripts). 2.) With PHP it is more obvious from your code what you are doing and can be easily documented inline.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the Apache mod_dav module in 10.04 (2.2.14 apache2) so that all files are created with the wrong permissions.

You can either:
- install apache 2.2.15 - I am thinking about that but I've no clue how to do that without breaking everything else!
- Upgrade to 10.10
- setup a crontab script to change the permissions

I've done the last one there. But looking for help on doing the first one.

See related bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+s...e2/+bug/540747